# Maintaining a personal differential using git

Tags: git, workflow

I have been working on some projects using Git and want to improve my work-flow for the same. I would like to know of a good approach to maintaining my own differential while working in a team. For example, I want to add some debugging utilities which suit me and work while using them, but don't want to introduce those changes into the team (remote) repository. The same goes for using my own config files etc.

I have thought about working on a different branch, but in that case I will have to undo my 'personal' changes, each time I merge my own branch into the master branch.

Is there a better way to do the same?

EDIT:

So, after some frolicking with Git I am able to come up with this:

From my 'master' branch, I typed

```
git checkout -b local
```

I then did some changes there. I first made a change to my config file, which I wanted to be exclusive and then did the work to push to remote repo. So, I had an exclusive commit in the beginning, followed by the commits which I would push to the remote repo. Then I checked out into my master branch and pulled in the latest code after a while.

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

and checked into my local branch again after a while. Then I checked out another branch from there

```
git checkout -b commit-work
```

and then

```
git rebase --onto master commit-work~3
```

where commit-work~3 referred to the last commit that I wanted to push.

Then I merged this branch into my master branch and I was all set!

But still, I would like to have a branch where I can resume working again. Currently, when I check out my local I have the commits which I did, but I can't figure out how to introduce the changes that were made to the master. Hope someone can help with that.

EDIT 2:

So, I have answered this thread myself, but I feel that it can be improved much still. The issues with this approach are, firstly I need to pull in changes for the master branch and the local branch separately. What's the best way to deal with this here? Also, this approach works fine in case one creates 'private' commits and the normal commits in separate groups. In what way can one deal with the case that all commits are made *disorderly*.

EDIT 3:

Looks like I have a satisfactory work-flow to work with now. But please suggest any improvements if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some messing around with, I have settled with this workflow for now..

From the *main* branch (the one that has the origin/remote configured), let's say it is the **master** branch, do

```
git checkout -b local
```

This will create a new branch by name of local and checkout the same.

Then one can make some personal changes there and make commits for the same.
Now lets say one has made two commits on this branch which are not to be pushed upstream (E & F), followed by three others that have to be (G, H & I), as figured below:

A - B - C - D   [master]

```
         \

          E - F - G - H - I  [local]
```

One now needs to checkout the master branch

```
git checkout master
```

and then simply do

```
git rebase --onto master F local
```

As can be inferred, the first argument for the git rebase command is the branch where you want all the commits to be finally, which in this case is the master branch. The second argument is the last commit, which you want to keep to your own codebase, while the last argument is the reference for the commit upto which the changes need to be pushed upstream. *local* here refers to the last commit in the local branch.

This way one can then push the commits from the master branch. Then in order to do any work, checkout the local branch, pull in the changes from the remote, and iterate the process.
Also, pulling in with the `--rebase` option will also assure that the private commits remain on top of the branch.

Edit:

It looks like I have an answer finally. I can easily continue working on my personal branch, after pushing to the remote and then pulling in my master branch by,

To continue working in the personal branch, firstly do

```
git push
git pull
git co local
```

then simply rebase the local branch with,

```
git rebase master
```

This must do the work.

Comment: [Maintaining a Git Differential](https://purezen.github.io/posts/maintaining-a-git-differential/)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use a private branch in this case, periodically rebasing my work (which would automatically undo my changes, bring the remote's changes in and apply my patches on top of that).

When you want to deliver some of your changes, you can rebase the master branch from your private branch (say a specific commit -- assuming you don't want to deliver all your changes). Then push your changes to the upstream master branch.

Edit:

Rebasing basically removes your local commits, pulls all the changes from the remote (fast-forwarding the changes. No need to do any merges since your commits were removed). Then it applies your local commits on top of the repository. At this point git will try to merge your changes with the code you had just pulled in.

So, for example, if you want to maintain local changes to a Github repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/rails/turbolinks.git
```

add your local changes

```
git add my-changed-file
git commit -m "local changes"
```

Now whenever the remote repository gets more commits you just rebase your's on top of them:

```
git pull --rebase
```

It gets slightly more complicated if you have some changes that you want to push to the remote repository and some local ones that you wish to keep. In this case I'd suggest you keep another branch and pull into the master branch only changes that you want to push to the remote.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. But can you be more elaborate? I am messing up with the 'rebase' command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use modified config file in development, you can use `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` to make git ignore your local changes to given file. File changes are ignored in your whole local repo, just like you would add given file to `.gitignore`.

More: [man git-update-index](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)

Comment: I want to maintain my personal set of changes to some files (which I want to be updated to and from the remote repo). Not exclude them from Git. For example, a Gemfile for a Rails env. where I would like to add my changes, as well as pull in changes from remote. But at the same time keep some changes (eg. some debugging/testing gems and other initializer files which their installation will create) for my local setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you're not going to add them to the main repository, why keep them in your local copy of the project repository? Create a new repository, keep your tools there, then use `PATH` (or whatever is appropriate for your environment) to access your tools. For local changes to config files that are in the main repository, see [the answer from @ciastek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27757347/1831052).

Comment: I intend to maintain some changes, not files if that is your question. I have commented on @ciastek answer for the same.